# How to use listagg parameter in Oracle procedure where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I group a series of IDs using LISTAGG.
Here is an example of a returned value-

```
A     1,2,3,4,5    PROC.ABC
B     6,7,8        PROC.ABC
C     2,3,4        PROC.DEF
```

I then try to use a cursor and pass each value into the following procedure:

```
PROCEDURE abc(id_list IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_a SET flag = 1 WHERE id IN (id_list);
END;
```

This errors out ("Invalid Number" error) because id_list is being inserted as

> '1,2,3,4,5'

, not

> 1,2,3,4,5

. How can I get this to work? I would prefer not to use dynamic SQL if possible.

Comment: If you control this design, don't use listagg and a string argument - create and pass a collection of numbers instead.

Comment: SQL has no native methods for handling CSV values. You'll have to write one, or switch to something supported like JSON, XML or as Alex suggested, a collection.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the idea, it took a awhile, but I was finally able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use listagg; create a collection type.

```
create or replace type t_vchar_tab as table of integer
```

Then replace listagg in the query-

```
CAST(COLLECT(id) AS t_vchar_tab) as id_list
```

Then the procedure should reference the collection w/use of MEMBER

```
PROCEDURE abc(id_list t_vchar_tab) IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_a SET flag = 1 WHERE id MEMBER OF id_list;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have APEX installed in your database, you can use the [APEX_STRING.SPLIT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.html#GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6) function to split your string by commas. If you know `id_list` is always going to be numbers, you can use `APEX_STRING.SPLIT_NUMBERS` as well.

```sql
PROCEDURE abc (id_list IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_a
       SET flag = 1
     WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (apex_string.split (id_list, ',')));
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to create a function that returns a list of values.

```
FUNCTION TVF_SPLIT (expression CLOB, delimiter CHAR) RETURN sys.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
AS
v_TYPE_TABLE_SEPRATOR sys.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST :=sys.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
v_xml_data CLOB;

BEGIN

v_xml_data := '<r><n>' || replace(expression,delimiter,'</n><n>') || '</n></r>';

SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO v_TYPE_TABLE_SEPRATOR FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM
            XMLTABLE ( '/r/*' 
            PASSING xmltype(v_xml_data) 
            COLUMNS 
                r VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '/n' 
            ) xmlt
    );

RETURN v_TYPE_TABLE_SEPRATOR;
END;

Select * from table(TVF_SPLIT('1,2,3,4,5',','));
```